# C# Devexpress, update report

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

Using C sharp, winforms, visual studio 2010, .NET 4 and devexpress API.

Hi guys I've recently attempted making a report using the devexpress xtreport control.
  It works fine and looks great, only problem is I need it to update during runtime.

The problem I have is when my controls are updated I need them to pass the values to my report,  So far this Isn't working nor is my xtrachart on the report, nothing updates.

I'm wandering what I should call to update the entire report if there is such a method.

Reason I'm using text box values to put into the report is due to the display of the report never changing and the fact I'm using small  amounts of data that gets processed within my winforms application.

Heres some code:

```
public partial class XtraReport1 : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
{
    DataTable chartTable3 = new DataTable("Table1");
    DataTable chartTable4 = new DataTable("Table2");
    DataTable chartTable5 = new DataTable("Table3");
    DataTable chartTable6 = new DataTable("Table4");
    public DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRChart xrChart1;

    public XtraReport1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void branchname(string bname)
    {
        branch.Text = bname;
    }


    public void names(string pg1k, string pg2k, string pg3k, string pg4k)
    {
        Pg1.Text = pg1k;
        Pg2.Text = pg2k;
        Pg3.Text = pg3k;
        Pg4.Text = pg4k;
    }

    public void TotalSalesk(string totS)
    {
        Sales.Text = totS;
    }

    public void TotalQtyk(string totQ)
    {
        Qty.Text = totQ;
    }

    public void SelectedSales(string pg1S, string pg2S, string pg3S, string pg4S)
    {
        //xrLabel1.Text = label1;
        Pg1Sales.Text = pg1S;
        Pg2Sales.Text = pg2S;
        Pg3Sales.Text = pg3S;
        Pg4Sales.Text = pg4S;
    }

    public void SelectedQty(string pg1Q, string pg2Q, string pg3Q, string pg4Q)
    {
        Pg1Qty.Text = pg1Q;
        Pg2Qty.Text = pg2Q;
        Pg3Qty.Text = pg3Q;
        Pg4Qty.Text = pg4Q;
    }

    public void PgGrpPercent(string pg1P, string pg2P, string pg3P, string pg4P)
    {
        Pg1Perc.Text = pg1P;
        Pg2Perc.Text = pg2P;
        Pg3perc.Text = pg3P;
        Pg4perc.Text = pg4P;
    }

    public void PgTop50(string pg1t5, string pg2t5, string pg3t5, string pg4t5)
    {
        Pg1T50.Text = pg1t5;
        Pg2T50.Text = pg2t5;
        Pg3T50.Text = pg3t5;
        Pg4T50.Text = pg4t5;
    }

    public void PgTop100(string pg1t1, string pg2t1, string pg3t1, string pg4t1)
    {
        Pg1T100.Text = pg1t1;
        Pg2T100.Text = pg2t1;
        Pg3T100.Text = pg3t1;
        Pg4T100.Text = pg4t1;
    }

    public void PgTop200(string pg1t2, string pg2t2, string pg3t2, string pg4t2)
    {
        Pg1T200.Text = pg1t2;
        Pg2T200.Text = pg2t2;
        Pg3T200.Text = pg3t2;
        Pg4T200.Text = pg4t2;
    }

    public void PgOver(string pg1tO, string pg2tO, string pg3tO, string pg4tO)
    {
        Pg1Over.Text = pg1tO;
        Pg2over.Text = pg2tO;
        Pg3over.Text = pg3tO;
        Pg4over.Text = pg4tO;
    }

    public void CheckClear(bool checkme)
    {
        if (checkme == true)
        {
            //DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRChart xrChart1;
            chartTable3.Clear();
            chartTable3.Columns.Clear();
            chartTable4.Clear();
            chartTable4.Columns.Clear();
            chartTable5.Clear();
            chartTable5.Columns.Clear();
            chartTable6.Clear();
            chartTable6.Columns.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void myChartSeries1(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table)
    {
        //xrChart1.Series.Clear();


            // Add two columns to the table.
            chartTable3.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            chartTable3.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
            chartTable3.Rows.Add("Below 50", top);
            chartTable3.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", tmid);
            chartTable3.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", bmid);
            chartTable3.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", bottom);

            Series series3 = new Series(pgName, ViewType.Bar);

            //.Series.Add(series1);
            series3.DataSource = chartTable3;

            series3.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;

            series3.ArgumentDataMember = "Names";  //error here

            series3.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;

            series3.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });

            //series1.Label.PointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series3.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series3.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;

            series3.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
            xrChart1.Series.Add(series3);

            xrChart1.Legend.Visible = true;


    }

    public void myChartSeries2(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table)
    {

            // Add two columns to the table.
            chartTable4.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            chartTable4.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
            chartTable4.Rows.Add("Below 50", top);
            chartTable4.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", tmid);
            chartTable4.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", bmid);
            chartTable4.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", bottom);

            Series series4 = new Series(pgName, ViewType.Bar);

            //.Series.Add(series1);
            series4.DataSource = chartTable4;

            series4.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;

            series4.ArgumentDataMember = "Names";

            series4.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;

            series4.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });

            //series1.Label.PointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series4.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series4.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;

            series4.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
            xrChart1.Series.Add(series4);

            xrChart1.Legend.Visible = true;        
    }

    public void myChartSeries3(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table)
    {

            // Add two columns to the table.
            chartTable5.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            chartTable5.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
            chartTable5.Rows.Add("Below 50", top);
            chartTable5.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", tmid);
            chartTable5.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", bmid);
            chartTable5.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", bottom);

            Series series5 = new Series(pgName, ViewType.Bar);

            //.Series.Add(series1);
            series5.DataSource = chartTable5;

            series5.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;

            series5.ArgumentDataMember = "Names";

            series5.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;

            series5.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });

            //series1.Label.PointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series5.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series5.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;

            series5.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
            xrChart1.Series.Add(series5);

            xrChart1.Legend.Visible = true;


    }

    public void myChartSeries4(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table)
    {

            // Add two columns to the table.
            chartTable6.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            chartTable6.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
            chartTable6.Rows.Add("Below 50", top);
            chartTable6.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", tmid);
            chartTable6.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", bmid);
            chartTable6.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", bottom);

            Series series6 = new Series(pgName, ViewType.Bar);

            //.Series.Add(series1);
            series6.DataSource = chartTable6;

            series6.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;

            series6.ArgumentDataMember = "Names";

            series6.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;

            series6.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });

            //series1.Label.PointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series6.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;

            series6.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;

            series6.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
            xrChart1.Series.Add(series6);

            xrChart1.Legend.Visible = true;


    }
}
```

I realise this code needs a lot of clear up work since it could be made a lot neater and shorter, but this is temporary to test out if I can get a the report to work.
Also please forgive the methods and variables with bad names, these are mapped on my design for my reference and will too be changed when this is completed and I can come up with some good names.

Many thanks.

copy of my report

[image]

@reniuz

```
namespace RepSalesNetAnalysis
{
public partial class MyPrintPreviewForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public MyPrintPreviewForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

    private void MyPrintPreviewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printControl1.PrintingSystem = report.PrintingSystem;
        //creating document
        report.CreateDocument();
    }

    public void addSeries1(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table1)
    {
        //calling your method in report
        report.myChartSeries1(top, tmid, bmid, bottom, pgName, table1);
        //recreate document
        //report.CreateDocument();
    }

    public void addSeries2(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table2)
    {
        //calling your method in report
        report.myChartSeries2(top, tmid, bmid, bottom, pgName, table2);
        //recreate document
        //report.CreateDocument();
    }

    public void addSeries3(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table3)
    {
        //calling your method in report
        report.myChartSeries3(top, tmid, bmid, bottom, pgName, table3);
        //recreate document
        //report.CreateDocument();
    }

    public void addSeries4(double top, double tmid, double bmid, double bottom, string pgName, bool table4)
    {
        //calling your method in report
        report.myChartSeries4(top, tmid, bmid, bottom, pgName, table4);
        //recreate document
        //report.CreateDocument();
    }

    public void addBranchName(string BranchName)
    {
        report.branchname(BranchName);
    }

    public void addNames(string pg1k, string pg2k, string pg3k, string pg4k)
    {
        report.names(pg1k, pg2k, pg3k, pg4k);
    }

    public void addTotalSalesk(string totS)
    {
        report.TotalSalesk(totS);
    }

    public void addTotalQtyk(string totQ)
    {
        report.TotalQtyk(totQ);
    }

    public void addSelectedSales(string pg1S, string pg2S, string pg3S, string pg4S)
    {
        report.SelectedSales(pg1S, pg2S, pg3S, pg4S);
    }

    public void addSelectedQty(string pg1Q, string pg2Q, string pg3Q, string pg4Q)
    {
        report.SelectedQty(pg1Q, pg2Q, pg3Q, pg4Q);
    }

    public void addPgGrpPercent(string pg1P, string pg2P, string pg3P, string pg4P)
    {
        report.PgGrpPercent(pg1P, pg2P, pg3P, pg4P);
    }

    public void addPgTop50(string pg1t5, string pg2t5, string pg3t5, string pg4t5)
    {
        report.PgTop50(pg1t5, pg2t5, pg3t5, pg4t5);
    }

    public void addPgTop100(string pg1t1, string pg2t1, string pg3t1, string pg4t1)
    {
        report.PgTop100(pg1t1, pg2t1, pg3t1, pg4t1);
    }

    public void addpgTop200(string pg1t2, string pg2t2, string pg3t2, string pg4t2)
    {
        report.PgTop200(pg1t2, pg2t2, pg3t2, pg4t2);
    }

    public void addPgOver(string pg1tO, string pg2tO, string pg3tO, string pg4tO)
    {
        report.PgOver(pg1tO, pg2tO, pg3tO, pg4tO,);
    }

}
}
```

where should i put the create document??

Comment: devexpress reports have parameters which can be inputted when report is shown. Maybe you should use them, not custom input

Comment: u mean user input when the report is shown? like I said I have textboxs that display the result of my calcs in my form.  I then take the values they display as input to the report.  hardcode assigning to the exact layout I need.  this reduces dynamics but I know the report never changes only the values, hence when my textboxes are updated I need the reports boxs updated too, as well as the info for the xtrachart. this needs to happen when I preview my report or just before preview

Comment: have you got a small example of what you mean?

Comment: Correct me if I understood correctly. You want thet after printpreview of report is shown you click button and want that new series appear in chart right? Before I thought that you want just update values in report(for example label text)

Comment: yup label texts and a chart ill attatch a picture of what it looks like

Comment: well with labels params would fit, but different story with chart. Ok I think I found solution, try to explain in answer.

Comment: you opening print preview like that `var r = new XtraReport1(); r.ShowPrieview();` ?

Comment: i instantiated the report class, and call it like this
    salesAnalysisReport.ShowPreview();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code to update report:

```
//XtraReport1 is your report
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
//Open print preview form
report.ShowPreview();

//Update your report content
report.myChartSeries2(1,2,3,4,DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
//Recreate/update document in print preview 
report.CreateDocument();
```

For more details and notes about CreateDocument() method visit [DevExpress documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_CreateDocumenttopic134)

Comment: theres a slight problem, when i close the printpreview form, then run the button again, it throws and exception error.
set { printControl1.PrintingSystem = value.PrintingSystem;  it says this needs a "new" keyword to create object

Comment: Ok stupid me :) you even dont need any custom form. Everything works fine when you use `XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1(); report.ShowPreview();` and when you need to refresh report call `report.CreateDocument();` So after all this mess the answer to your question use CreateDocument to refresh it :)...after second cup of coffee brains started to work :)

Comment: lmao, so all i needed after all was that one line haha

Comment: yeah :D one post from devexpress support mislead me totally.

Comment: it works, now updates, unfortunatly mycharts seems to keep the results from last time and combines it with the new data.  i think its a simple clear or something in the tables im using...i hope.  Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Quick update, reason was because i forgot to clear the chart series before i re-created xD

Comment: You welcome. To clear charts you need to clear chart series list before showing print preview.